# PHP database connection issue when run in Terminal

Tags: php, mysql, terminal, cron

I have a simple php file I want to execute in the terminal:

script.php

```
echo "script is running";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "Connection Established\n"; 
}
mysql_close($con);
```

I'm running the script in the terminal on MacOs with `php script.php`, and I'm getting the following error:

```
script is running
Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/issueManager3/notifications.php on line 5
Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

However, when I run the script through a web browser, it connects to the database fine.

Am I missing something? Or is there something else I need to set up to achieve database connections through the terminal?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if they're not loading two different configuration files? On the command line execute

    php --ini

And then create a file to be interpreted by the instance you're serving to the web with the following content:

    <?php php_info(INFO_GENERAL); ?>

Comment: @paperless Yes the configuration file in the terminal is different. How do I change it?